# How can i fix this flutter error in android studio?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

when i run my flutter app in Android Studio i have this problem , so i need your help please
[that it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ3xk.jpg).jpg

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

that url https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-3.5.0-all.zip will be there in gradle-wrapper.properties file.

so you can go to android/gradle/wrapper directory and find that file.

update distribution url to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip and it should work.

3.5 is very old. not sure why you want to use it.